# Was the word 男朋友 borrowed from English (or maybe the opposite)?

Tags: etymology, history

男朋友 and 女朋友 have the same thought process as their English counterparts, as in both words are compounded of *(the gender) + ("friend")*, even though they're actually used to refer to a romantic partner of said gender. Are there any linguistic reasons for that? Did English and Chinese-speaking nations have any contact in the past or have these 2 isolated and totally different nations had the same logic for this word specifically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

The English words boyfriend/girlfriend are [modern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girlfriend#Etymology); their usage to refer to romantic, unmarried relations dates to around 1922. This is also where other terms like "dating" arose.

Similarly, in Chinese, [男朋友/女朋友 do not exist in pre-modern times](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A5%B3%E6%9C%8B%E5%8F%8B#%E8%AF%8D%E6%BA%90). Other terms like 佳人 would be used.

The [Republican Era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_of_the_Republican_era_in_China) saw big changes in Chinese culture and adoption of Western culture and language. It would be easy to conclude, therefore, that the words 男朋友/女朋友 were borrowed from English during this time.

Answer (score -1):

I think in English we say boy/girl friend for friendship and boyfriend/girlfirend for relationship. In Chinese, the counterpart is 男性(Xing )朋友/女性(Xing )朋友 for friendship. 男朋友/女朋友 indicates relationship in general.